# C++ Output Stream Operator Overload With Persistent IOManip

Tags: c++, io, iostream, outputstream, iomanip

I've used a friend function to give my 2d-array class `operator<<` capabilities.

Now, I want to call:

```
cout<<setprecision(3)<<setw(4)<<MY_CLASS<<endl;
```

And have my 2d-array class apply the precision and width of the stream to each of its elements.

Inside, the code has a line like:

```
output_stream<<MY_CLASS(x,y);
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can read all the current formatting flags, save them and apply them before every individual output operation. Something like Boost's format saver may help you with that.

Comment: Does this mean that your `operarotr<<` isn't writing to the given `ostream&` directly but uses a temporary first and you want to apply the same settings to that temporary output ?

Comment: @KerrekSB, perhaps you could provide a link to this "format saver" you speak of? Alas, this seems a somewhat circuitous way of solving the problem...

Comment: I don't follow you, @J.N. Could you reword?

Comment: @Richard : if you use `setprecision()` or any other modifiers they'll apply until you explicitely remove/change them. That is you may have nothing to do unless you are using another stream before writing to `cout`.

Comment: @J.N., that does seem to be the case with `setprecision()`, but `setw()` only applies to the next insertion operation (ala: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/).

Comment: @Richard: [Here you go](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html). I'm afraid iostreams *are* just a bit... circuitous.

Comment: @Richard : indeed, my mistake, sorry. You can have a look at the `width()` function and see if it can be use for your purpose.